# How to concatenate values in two hstore postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Soppose i have 2 hstores:

```
'"MarkingCount"=>"0","BaseCount"=>"6","EgaisCount"=>"0","MercuryCount"=>"3"':: hstore
'"MarkingCount"=>"1","BaseCount"=>"15","EgaisCount"=>"65","MercuryCount"=>"35"':: hstore
```

How to concatenate them usning postgresql, that results will be:
`'"MarkingCount"=>"1","BaseCount"=>"21","EgaisCount"=>"65","MercuryCount"=>"38"`'

Operation hstore || hstore is not the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `each()` to make rows of your `hstore`, aggregate with `sum()`, and then turn the result back into an `hstore`.

```
with hs(id, val) as (
  values (1, '"MarkingCount"=>"0","BaseCount"=>"6","EgaisCount"=>"0","MercuryCount"=>"3"':: hstore), 
         (2, '"MarkingCount"=>"1","BaseCount"=>"15","EgaisCount"=>"65","MercuryCount"=>"35"':: hstore)
), agg as (
  select key, sum(value::int) as value
    from hs h
   cross join lateral each(val) as e(key, value)
   group by key
)
select hstore(array_agg(key), array_agg(value::text)) as result
  from agg;

                                      result                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "BaseCount"=>"21", "EgaisCount"=>"65", "MarkingCount"=>"1", "MercuryCount"=>"38"
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you help me with following: adding condition where keys mathes before casting sum(value::int), cause i have error something like  invalid input syntax for integer: "True"

Comment: @AlexNikitin You can tackle that a couple of different ways.  Can you exclude by name?  For instance, all the keys in your example end with `Count`.  If not, then matching by regex should work.  Can you please open a new question with example data?